# What is driving the flow of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics

Recently, I had watched one of the viral videos on the internet about [an unconventional way of fishing using banana trunks.](https://youtu.be/Thc83vL8FWY) I am unable to see what is driving the flow of water? Is it a 'plain difference in height' or something more complex?

Comment: Cool video. You guessed right. Difference in height.

Answer (score 0):

The submerged end of the banana trunk experiences static fluid pressure which is above atmospheric, due to the height of the fluid above it; its magnitude is given by $\rho gh$ in which $h$ is the depth to which the end of the banana trunk has been submerged ($\rho$ is water density, $g$ is gravitational acceleration). Provided that the other end of the banana trunk is below the level of water in the river, there will be a flow through the trunk driven by a pressure difference $\Delta p=\rho g \Delta h$ in which $\Delta h$ is the height difference between outlet end of the banana trunk and water level in river.

If the axis of the banana trunk has been at least to some extent aligned along local river-flow direction, such that flow is directed into the trunk, then an additional contribution to pressure difference is obtained, of magnitude $\rho u^2/2$, in which $u$ is the component of the local flow velocity along the banana trunk's axis.

P.S. I guess the role of conical thorn envelope fixed inside the submerged end of the banana trunk is to make the exit of the fish difficult once it enters.